# Tensorflow.strided_slice missing argument 'strides'?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run `cifar10_train.py` according to tutorials, but I got

```
"cifar10_input.py", line 87, in read_cifar10
tf.strided_slice(record_bytes, [0], [label_bytes]), tf.int32)
TypeError: strided_slice() missing 1 required positional argument: 'strides'
```

The document says that `strides` is optional, and it did work properly on Ubuntu before.

My tensorflow version is 0.12.0rc1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64. I have already installed the newest release.

May I have to pass this argument? I have no idea about it...

UPDATE: I replaced strided_slice with slice, and it works. According to issue#754, `strides` will be optional at 1.0 release. (maybe?)

Answer (score 6):

Replace a line

```
tf.strided_slice(record_bytes, [0], [label_bytes]), tf.int32)
```

to the line:

```
tf.strided_slice(record_bytes, [0], [label_bytes], [1]), tf.int32)
```

and a line in the next operator

```
[label_bytes + image_bytes]),
```

to the line

```
[label_bytes + image_bytes], [1]),
```

It works for me.

Comment: This solves this problem but does not address a seperate issue of deprecated function calls which I immediately ran into after this. @MartinThoma has given the comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 5):

@user3143469 already gave the desired answer.

Going to TF 0.12, there are several things in the cifar10 tutorial which need to be updated (see [pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/785)).

See https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/commit/38ce1f87d6e4396cde64fe831c2ead2507781270 for the changes which need to be made and [this folder](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/tree/master/ML/tf-cifar-10) for working code + instructions how to use it.

Comment: This is the comprehensive answer which solves the problem stated as well as others you will run into.

Comment: @Martin. I cloned your modified code and upon running I am getting an error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'per_image_standardization` my tensorflow11, cudnn and cuda8 are correctly installed

Comment: " upon running I am getting an error" Please be more exact. What exactly did you run? Could you paste the complete output e.g. to http://pastebin.com/?